# Windows 8 Spell checking provider

Tags: c++, windows, windows-8, spell-checking, provider

I'm trying to implement my own Spell Check provider for Windows 8. I have a class which receives a word and returns the correct word, however, I cannot find the class or function in the [Spell Checking Provider Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/spell-checking-provider-4cbec195) by Microsoft where I receive the user input string and return for it the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are implementing a spell checking provider, you will be implementing the [ISpellCheckProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh869789%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface. (In the sample you refer to, this is implemented by the SampleSpellCheckProvider class)

There are actually two phases for spell checking. The first is checking to see whether some text contains any errors and the second is providing suggestions.

The first phase happens in the call to [Check](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh869794%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In this you are provided the text to check and you return a class which implements [IEnumSpellingError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh869751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that class should cache the text and return any errors that it finds in calls to [Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh869752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). (You can find an implementation of IEnumSpellingError in the EnumSpellingError class in the sample. In the sample, it ends up calling EngineCheck on the provider (an internal method) which calls FindFirstError on SampleEngine -- the actual checking and suggesting being isolated into the SampleEngine.h file while the others focus on the infrastructure)

The second phase happens in the call to [Suggest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh869804%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In this you are given a word and return the set of suggestions as a class which implements [IEnumString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687257%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Great Explanation Thanks! Maybe this information should also be provided in [About the Spell Checking API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh869748(v=vs.85).aspx )