# Add spell check languages for the Windows built-in spell check provider

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, spell-checking

I am trying to use the Windows built-in spell checker in my c++ app. I am going through the official spell check client sample found [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Spell-checking-client-aea0148c/view/Discussions/0?showDiscussionForm=True&UserMetadataUpdate=1).

When running the sample, `ISpellCheckerFactory::get_SupportedLanguages` returns 4 languages for my machine: en-CA, en-LR, en-PH and en-US. `ISpellCheckerFactory::CreateSpellChecker` returns the Windows built-in spell checker, as can be seen by calling `ISpellChecker::get_Id` and `ISpellChecker::get_LocalizedName` which return "MsSpell" and "Microsoft Windows Spellchecker", respectively.

Where do those 4 languages come from? How can I install more spell check languages for the built-in spell checker? Can my application request Windows to install new spell check languages for the MsSpell provider?

The MSDN doc doesn't seem to have any info around the built-in spell check provider. I have tried adding new languages in my Windows settings, changing the "default" language, and adding keyboard inputs, but no matter what I try, the list of supported spell check languages does not change.

Comment: what windows version?

Comment: I am running Windows 10 version 1709, but the intent is for the app to run on Windows 8 and Windows 10

Comment: I'm guessing you install them through the Language page in Settings.

Comment: If you're trying to add more of the standard Windows spell checkers for other languages, your question is probably more suitable for [su] instead. If you're wanting to write your own spell checker and install it into Windows, then you may find [Windows 8 spell checking provider](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11986936/62576) helpful, as it has links both to the documentation of the API and a sample of a working spell check provider you can install and use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new language (France) and install basic typing. I test on Windows 10 17763 using official sample [Spell Checking Client](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/SpellCheckerClient/cpp), it works.

Before install the new language:

[image]

After install the new language:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hmm, in my language settings, the "Language pack" and "Basic typing" sections are not there, no matter which language I add. Maybe it has something to do with my corp environment. In any case, your answer confirms how to add spell check languages, so thank you.